# Mysql - blocked execut query

Tags: mysql

I'm having a problem using ubuntu 14.04. Mysql. When I run a query the Mysql hangs I would like to know if it has how to track via log all occurrences. Look what else I found did not help much.

/var/log/messages

Thank you very much!

---

I went inside the directory has no file with this name, but I found the file error.log. Are the same thing? I opened it out of curiosity and found various InnoDB events. Thank you very much! If you can help me, thank you.

---

This is a message for error.log
[Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.

Comment: what error messages are you getting ?

Comment: [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.

Comment: @Fagnernascimentosouza When posting more information to your question, please [edit your question instead of writing an answer](http://askubuntu.com/posts/862651/edit).

Comment: Please look at restructuring you question add the __script your trying to run__, __error messages__, any other activity done before the issue began.

Answer (score 0):

Enable slow query logging:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609257/how-to-enable-mysql-slow-query-log

Take note of what version of MySQL you are using when configuring it but the log should then appear at `/var/log/mysql/slow-query.log`

Comment: I went inside the directory has no file with this name, but I found the file error.log. Are the same thing? I opened it out of curiosity and found various InnoDB events. Thank you very much! If you can help me, thank you.

Comment: Enable the slow query log then verify it's working by checking the server variable. After that you should see it in the query log. Also take note that technically if the query never returns it will never be written to the slow query log (since it has to finish timing it to write the log)  - in that case run a `SHOW PROCESSLIST` query to see if it's still running.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Tanks this resolve my problem.. (y)